# In MacOS, what is the keyboard shortcut to switch to the last used window?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

Currently when I try to do cmd+tab, it does not go to the last used window. Instead it cycles through some predefined order.

I want it to go to the last used window.

Answer (score 0):

[Hyperswitch](https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch) allows the user to alt-tab to the last used window rather than MacOS's predefined cycle.